# How do i convert a pdf file to a .txt file containing the page number?

Tags: pdf, txt, file-conversion

I’m trying to figure out how to convert a pdf file to a .txt file that contains the pdf page numbers.

I’ve googled it, searched on reddit and watched some videos on youtube.

Comment: Be more specific... you want a txt file that contains only the page numbers or the total pages number? Or are you looking for an ocr system?

Comment: @GicuAftene i want to create a document containing the text from a pdf file. With numbers in between showing where page 1 is, page 2 etc.

Comment: Gotcha, there are a lot of python scripts that allow you to perform an OCR, probably you could find something to make a "page by page" text recognition system just modifying that scripts.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

Comment: The [DocumentConverter](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/doxc/documentconverter.html) class from the LEADTOOLS Document library can convert PDF to TXT and insert the page numbers in the output file when configured through the [TextDocumentOptions](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/ft/textdocumentoptions.html). If you wish to try this, you can find a free evaluation [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads). (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)

Answer (score 0):

using pdf to text we can check if all pages already have a number so for example here it is top right on all 6 pages

[image]

However if it was not there and we wanted the text to be injected at top of each page we could run

```
for /L %a in (1,1,6) do echo Page %a >>out.txt&pdftotext -f %a -l %a -layout -enc UTF-8 -fixed 4 C:\Apps\PDF\poppler\22.11.0\Library\bin\Filename.pdf temp.txt&type temp.txt>>out.txt
```

then we get the 6 pages starting with the Page # at the top left also

[image]